# Problema com o retorno de uma condição

Tags: python, condição, filtro, diretório

Estou fazendo um script que printa as pastas vazias e depois as apaga. Tudo isso dentro de um diretório geral ("D:/test/").
O que esta acontecendo de errado é que eu percorro as pastas e confiro se o tamanho dela é igual a 0. Inicialmente, se o tamanho==0, ele só printa o caminho da pasta (apenas para verificar). Mas ao invés dele printar só as pastas vazias, ele acaba retornando caminhos que contém tamanho diferente de 0.

```
import os

path = 'D:/test'
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            x = os.path.join(dirname.replace(os.path.sep, '/'), subdirname).replace(os.path.sep, '/')
            if os.path.getsize(x) == 0:
                print(x)
                print("__________________________________________________________")
            # try:
            #     if Path(x).stat().st_size == 0:
            #         # os.rmdir(x)
            #         print(x)
            #         print("__________________________________________________________")
            # except OSError as e:
            #     print("Error: %s : %s" % (x, e.strerror))
            # print(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

A entrada da pasta em si não tem tamanho. Tens que percorrer os ficheiros dessa pasta para saber o tamanho.

```
import os

def get_size(start_path = '.'):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_path):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            if not os.path.islink(fp):
                total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)

    return total_size

path = 'folder_root'
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            x = os.path.join(dirname.replace(os.path.sep, '/'), subdirname).replace(os.path.sep, '/')
            if get_size(x) == 0:
                print(x)
                print("__________________________________________________________")
```